# Events not firing within use tag

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have been experimenting with the `use` tag within an `svg` tag. It seems relatively simple and I have a basic example working in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cneLLLqu/

Clicking on the red square (outside of the `defs` and `use` tags) yields a message box. Clicking on the green square does not fire any click event. I don't understand why events fire with the red square but not with the green. Inspecting the element everything looks fine.

I am currently using Opera 42.

Comment: I should clarify, the goal is to create standalone/encapsulated elements which can be reused multiple times. The elements would have internal events which would manipulate their appearance. 

This test of first principles is attempting to determine the reason behind why events aren't firing when defined within an object that is "used".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible. From the SVG 1.1 spec:

> The effect of a ‘use’ element is as if the contents of the referenced
>   element were deeply cloned into a separate non-exposed DOM tree which
>   had the ‘use’ element as its parent and all of the ‘use’ element's
>   ancestors as its higher-level ancestors. Because the cloned DOM tree
>   is non-exposed, the SVG Document Object Model (DOM) only contains the
>   ‘use’ element and its attributes. The SVG DOM does not show the
>   referenced element's contents as children of ‘use’ element.

Answer (score 0):

They must be completely independent and you don't have to use `<use>`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect id="rect-1" fill="#D0011B" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" onclick="alert('rect-1 clicked!')"></rect>
    <rect id="rect-2" fill="#4990E2" x="70" y="0" width="50" height="50" onclick="alert('rect-2 clicked!')"></rect>
</svg>
```

I just saw the comment you made in the other answer and in that case you have to add the `onclick` handler to the `<use>` tag not the `defs` element.

```
<use xlink:href="#test" x="60" y="0" onclick="alert('clicked')">
```

Comment: Is there a way to leave the event code within the realm of the objects that are referenced? Eventually these objects will be referenced from another file, and I'd rather the code live there.

Comment: I don't think you can because the actual object is the `<use>` one, the other one is just a template.